# Monitor Files/Polling or File Watcher in FTP location using Java

Tags: java, spring, ftp, spring-integration, file-watcher

I was using File Watcher to monitor files in local. Is there any way to monitor files in FTP. I have heard Spring Integration. Does Spring integration solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It does, but that’s not an event handling since there is no listener hook in the remote files protocols. So, we do polling periodically for changes in the remote dir.

See more info in docs : https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ftp.html#ftp-inbound

Comment: Can you share a example code to explain the same.

Comment: Well, I would the doc I have shared with you is good enough, but here is a sample anyway: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/main/basic/ftp